# Manually moving transcluded content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive `foo` whose template includes a list via `ng-repeat`:

```
<div>
  <h5>I want to insert transcluded template into body of the li:</h5>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat='item in items'>
       <!-- need item template here -->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want the template for each item to (optionally) to be specifiable at the point of usage of the directive:

```
<foo items='people'>
   <h5>{{item.name}}</h5>
</foo>

<foo items='people'>
  {{item.name}} is {{item.age}} years old.
</foo>
```

So I need the innerHTML of the directive (e.g. `<h5>{{item.name}}</h5>`) to be copied to the marked location in the directive template.

`<ng-transclude>` does this, but it gives the transcluded items the scope of the directive rather than the item. I also need to be able to optionally pull the item template from somewhere else. So I need to do the transclusion manually.

I have access to the transcluded content during `link:`, but at that point the list item in question is gone!

```
<div>
  <h5>I need to insert transcluded template into body of the li:</h5>
  <ul>
    <!-- ngRepeat: item in items -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

I think I need to do it during compile, but the transclusion function passed to the compile function is deprecated.

---

[Found a way to do it with a second directive, but that seems unnecessary...](http://plnkr.co/edit/dIPNy9hjf4Fqom8tUYPU?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using $interpolate service and changing a bit your approach please see demo here http://plnkr.co/edit/bSb7fEWiMTdNVJYyiXD8?p=preview

set your dynamic template as attribute in directive.

```
<foo template="'<h1>{{item.name}}</h1>'" items="people"></foo>
```

and change your directive to :

```
app.directive('foo', function($interpolate) {
    return {
        scope: {
          items: '=',
          template:'='
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'foo-template.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, controller, transclude) {

          //interpolate your template like below
          scope.getValue= function(item) {
           var exp = $interpolate(scope.template);
           var result =exp({item:item})
           return result;

          }
        }
    }
    });
```

and in your template use ng-bind-html

```
 <li ng-repeat='item in items'>
      <div ng-bind-html="getValue(item)"></div>
    </li>
```

don't forget to add **ngSanitize** module to your app

Comment: Templates may be elaborate. I don't want to force people to smash it into a string. We're porting from Silverlight where it's routine to declare an item template in an item container -- I'd like to maintain this in angular. It seems technically possible: I just want to move a chunk of HTML from the body of the directive into the template, but I've beat my head against it for an entire day trying to figure out how to do it in Angular.

I tried using your approach, with the `get` method returning the transcluded content, but I'm getting "unsafe" errors.

Comment: I updated with a solution I found, which requires a second directive. This is the affect I was trying to achieve, anyway, at least for transcluded content. I also need to be able to supply the template via other means, which I'll work on next.